# Google Maps - Zoom out when info window is closed or other radio button filter is "ticked"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need this map to zoom out to "2" when 2 things happen:

1. When you close the info window
2. When you click another radio button

I have tried a few things but nothing seems to work.

Here is my code:

```
var map;

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(58, 16),
        zoom: 2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
}

var seg = {
    1:'invesCastProd',
    2:'forged',
    3: 'airframe',
    5: 'corp',
    6: 'structurals'

}

var comp = {
    1:'structurals',
    2:'airfoils',
    3: 'airfoils',
    4: 'wyman',
    5: 'energy',
    6: 'strucComp',
    7: 'mechHard',
    8: 'engineProd',
    9: 'corp',
    10: 'aero',
    12: 'timet',
    13: 'specMetals'

}

var myJSON = {};
var myMarkers=[];

$.getJSON("locations.json", function(json1) {
  myJSON=json1;
  $.each(json1, function(key, data) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.latitude, data.longitude); 
    // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng
    });
    myMarkers[key]=marker;
    marker.setMap(map);

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

      if (infoWindow) {infoWindow.close();}
      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<h5>" + data.display_name + "</h5>" +
        "<div>" + data.street+ "</div>" +
        "<div>" + data.city + ", " + data.state + " &nbsp; " + data.postal_code + "</div>" +
        "<div class='mapPhoneNum'>" + data.telephone + "</div>" +
        "<div><strong>" + seg[data.segment_id] + "</strong></div>" +
        "<div><strong>" + comp[data.component_id] + "</strong></div>" +
        "<a href=" + data.web_url + ">Website</a>"
      });
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      map.setZoom(15);
      map.panTo(this.getPosition());

    });

    filterMarkers = function(category){
        //console.log(category);

        console.log(category.data());
        var component = category.data("component_id");
        var segment = category.data("segment_id")

        // Clear markers
        setMapOnAll(null);
        //marker = [];
        var filteredMarkers=[];

        $.each(myJSON, function(key, data) {
          //console.log(key);

          if( (myJSON[key].component_id == component) && (myJSON[key].segment_id == segment) ){
            console.log("FOUND");

            filteredMarkers.push(key);
          }
        });

        for(i=0;i<filteredMarkers.length;i++){
          myMarkers[filteredMarkers[i]].setMap(map);
        }
      }

    function setMapOnAll(map) {
      for (var i = 0; i < myMarkers.length; i++) {
        myMarkers[i].setMap(map);
      }
    }
});
```

});

what is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On close of an `InfoWindow` is the question.

You need an event listener for that.

Just add this in your "marker click" listener:
   (`google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {`) - Line #55 of `script.js`.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow,'closeclick',function(){
    console.log("CLOSE");
    map.setZoom(2);
    map.setCenter({lat:58,lng:16});
});
```

It sounds weird to add a listener into a listener, I know.
But that's where you define your infoWindow...
;)
It works!

**EDIT**
*(I didn't took care of the second request in the above...)*

So, have to move the above into a function:

```
function resetMapOrigin(){
    console.log("Reseting Map.");
    map.setZoom(2);
    map.setCenter({lat:58,lng:16});
}
```

Then call this "reset" function when you want.
;)

in `google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {`:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow,'closeclick',function(){
    resetMapOrigin();    // See Plunker line #72
});
```

and in `filterMarkers = function(category){`, right after `setMapOnAll(null);`:

```
resetMapOrigin();    // See Plunker line #90
```

[**Updated Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/mcvozo6l74Tlyk4aTovg?p=preview)